# How important is it to stop other colleagues' initiatives?

Tags: competition

We all have our "territories" and tasks/responsibilities we want to protect.
I once observed somebody saying "this data is mine, this other analyst can't have it", and that data led to very interesting results.

Now I find myself being the informal lead on some customer interactions, but some of my colleagues are very "enthusiastic" and are happy to reach out directly to customers in my territory. However, I am remote and they are not.

My colleagues are brilliant, but I want to keep coordinating work for these customers to support a promotion in a future leadership role.
Should I systematically "stop them there", or let everybody contribute freely?

How important is it for my career to stop my colleagues from taking initiative with things I am following?

Comment: Is this revenue related, or just reputation?  I mean, does working with these customers result in a commission on sales for you personally that might be affected by your colleague stealing it?

Comment: no commission, but I am remote and I need as much credit as possible for my work.

Comment: Is having your coworkers directly contact the client causing problems with the project?

Comment: Toxic environments are created by toxic executives. Are you sure you're currently working in a toxic environment? If you're remote and they are not, note that they can more easily badmouth you to important colleagues if you obstruct them. Also, if you're remote and they're not, it may be that you may be more dependent on people at the home office to get things for you than they are on you, but it's likely that no one will want to help you if you develop this reputation of not sharing/not helping anyone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ask your boss what you are supposed to do.

There must be a company policy on this, and if there isn't, it's high time.
Several people from an organization approaching one customer without properly defined roles and responsibilities leads to communication problems with the customer, frustration on their and your side, and possible financial repercussions (losing customers).

As others have already written, **this is not about you**. If you and your colleagues let your personal preferences be more important than business interest, you may find yourself being fired sooner or later.

Comment: How asking his boss would help? His question is focused on his own ambitions. His boss can't give him an answer that would support that can he? He will just suggest a conservative best to the business approach. But that's not what the OP is looking for. I think @Oled marks the spot by suggesting to make these people allies instead of blockers

Answer (score 7):

To me, your first paragraph describes a toxic work environment - where people vie for "power" and protect their little corners - without thinking of the larger picture - what's best for the company as a whole.

I see this mind set as very short sighted and ultimately destructive.

> How important is it for my career to stop my colleagues from taking initiative with things I am following?

How about trying to be open with everyone? How about trying to do things in such a way that the company gets the best results as possible - so it gives the best service to your clients?

If you are indeed the coordinator and the person who gets these results to your clients (and are not shy about showing that this is what you do), chances are that such an approach will do good to your career.

I would advise against having these fiefdoms and thinking about sharing and collaborating **more** with your colleagues - don't fall to the misconceptions of "if my colleague gets/does X, I am losing out". Consider that improving the organisation could very well mean more for everyone.

Comment: Keep in mind that one person doesn't make a culture. OP could simply have picked up an idea from a single toxic individual.

Comment: +1 The environment the OP describes where everyone is trying to one-up each other sounds like a horrible place to work.

Answer (score 4):

> How important is it for my career to stop my colleagues from taking initiative with things I am following?

Oh, it's extremely important. In the sense that **it's a terrible idea and could have a very large negative impact** on the career progression you're after. This is what I like to call a Career Limiting Move.

The nature of a career is such that as some point you're going to have to **shift from  "doing great work" to "enabling others to do great work"**. Like it or not but *every* career involves a significant management component. Most careers end with you doing nothing *but* managing others, but even technical specialists or domain experts need to know how to work with people and know how and where to share their knowledge with others. The people who can truly work on their own and be successful are a rare breed.

And it sounds like you're approaching the point where you have to shift gears. Most people reach that point over time and are promoted into leadership roles. But others grow into it naturally as they find that the work they're responsible for keeps growing to the point where it makes sense to bring in other people to share the load and continue growing. These are *excellent* career accelerators and if you're the ambitious sort you'd be a fool not to make full use of them. If you form a team under you who work for clients that you are the lead on, wouldn't that reflect very positively on you? You could probably draw in a lot more business for your company in the regions you're responsible for if you get good people working for or with you.

Now that said, making this switch isn't easy. Managing people is a tricky business and the one rule that holds for every new manager is that you're going to get it wrong. Several times. Some people also have trouble letting go of job tasks that they've become good at but delegation is part of the deal. But if you're really after a career then this is something you're going to need to learn.

Finally, there *are* situations where the advice above won't give you good results. If you're in a highly competitive sales environment and/or if there's no clear business case in moving you to a team lead position, such as if you've reached market saturation in the regions you're working for. And badly run companies may fail to recognise what you're doing and fail to reward you for it, instead promoting the guy tooting his own horn under your guidance. That's a risk and you'd know best what your company culture is like. But a career is not tied to a single company and your professional reputation is very important in getting you the opportunities you need to grow your career. **If you can't advance at your current company without backstabbing your colleagues, that's not a place you want to build a career**. Some people thrive in that kind of situation but it's completely incompatible with "professional" behaviour and you won't find advice on doing that on this site.

Comment: Very helpful answer overall. One small objection. I think he is at the stage that he still has not proven himself to the company that's why he sees these colleagues as blockers. He is not at the stage yet that you describe

Comment: @smith Possibly. It's certain that he might not feel ready, that's typical for this kind of career progression, but if he's already turned into some kind of an informal lead then with some attention spent on making his and his colleagues' achievements more visible then he will be at that stage. My hunch is that he's ready to take this one and just needs to change the way he looks at this but you're right that you need some amount of political capital to make this transition. Of course in that case it should be more about enforcing boundaries rather than blocking colleagues.

Answer (score 1):

**Look at long term impact on career and near term gain for you company**

What I mean by this is while making a decision on what to do and what not to do, important thing to figure is how is this helping the company? Do not worry how it will immediately help your career. People putting their career for every action they take is exactly what results in corporate politics and leg-pulling.

If sharing data with your 'brilliant' colleagues is good for your customers and hence for your company, you should totally do that, irresecptive of what good or bad you think it will do to your career.  That is your main job.

Having said this, you obviously need to look out for your career and assess if it is progressing as per your ambitions or not. Ideally, doing things which are good for your company, should gain high visibility and help in career progression. Although it can very well happen that due to poor management, your actions are overseen and if you think putting company's benefit above your own has negatively impacted your career, then you probably are at the wrong place